# How to determine unknown variables in a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Could somebody show me the steps involved in solving this problem:

Determine $a,b$ and $c$ so that $(x-1)^3$ is a factor of:
$$x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx -4.$$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please update your question with information about what you have already tried.

Comment: Multiply out $(x-1)^3,$ then ask yourself what would it mean for that to be a factor.

Comment: I have multiplied it out, but I don't know how to obtain a zero through synthetic division

Answer (score 1):

$$q(x)=x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx -4$$

one way is state that:

$$q(1)=0\\
q'(1)=0\\
q''(1)=0$$

can you finish?

Comment: No I can't finish

Comment: @SevanHotakorzian: why? don't you know derivative or can't you use that?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the product of the roots of the given polynomial is $4$ and we know that $(x - 1)^3$ is a factor of this polynomial. We need four roots, and so we know the other factor is $x +4$. Multiply these two and equate coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You want:
$$
x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx-4=(x-1)^3(x+4)
$$
where we have the factor $(x+4)$ because the product must have a term of degree $4$ with coefficient $1$ and a constant term of value $-4$.

Calculate the RHS and use the identity of polynomials.

Comment: Maybe you should explain how you get the factor $x+4$.

Comment: Because the constant term of the polynomial at LHS is $-4$ so this must be the product of the constant therms in the factors at the RHS.

Comment: I mean in the text.

Comment: Sorry!  It's better now?

Comment: Perfect.... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x-1=y$. You are asked to determine $a,b$ and $c$ so that $y^3$ is a factor of

$$(y+1)^4 + a(y+1)^3 + b(y+1)^2 + c(y+1) -4.$$

Expanding, we get

$$y^4+4y^3+6y^2+4y+1+ay^3+3ay^2+3ay+a+by^2+2by+b+cy+c-4$$ and we need to cancel the terms of degree $0,1$ and $2$,

$$\begin{cases}6+3a+b&=0,\\4+3a+2b+c&=0,\\1+a+b+c-4&=0.\end{cases}$$

$$a=1,b=-9,c=11.$$

Then the polynomial is

$$y^4+5y^3=(x+4)(x-1)^3$$ (as could be expected by evaluating at $x=0$).